# display an image

Tags: .net, asp.net

i want to display an image in asp page when page is loaded. the particular image is stored in database. in database the field's datatype is image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you would normally implement a HttpHandler that reads the image from the database and writes it to the response stream.

Something like this, but you would read the image data from the database instead of from the file system: http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/687/http-handlers-to-handle-images/

Also, it is simple to find a solution if you google it: http://www.google.com/search?q=httphandler+asp.net+image+database